# Ignore duplicate import statements in sonar

Tags: groovy, sonarqube, code-duplication

I have a Groovy project that's being analyzed by Sonar 3.0.1.  We have duplicate code detection turned on, using the Sonar detector.

In one set of files, it's detecting 11 lines of duplicated `import` statements.  In another set of files, it's detecting 15 lines of duplicated member declarations.  Since this project has a clear separation of database-vs-display objects (even though they're mostly similar, hence the duplicated member declarations), I'd like to configure Sonar to ignore these sets of duplications -- we consider them to be acceptable duplications.

How can I tell Sonar to ignore duplicated imports and/or member declarations, but still yell at me for duplicated code inside methods?

Comment: Has this been resolved? (having at the same issue) (if so please provide a answer :)

Comment: Any updates on this? having the same issue. Any way to get around the duplicated imports?

Comment: Still not resolved. imports considered duplicates in typescript code